# Best way to get input array key value with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got the following code to get the value of input name array key with javascript:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var value = input.name.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];

console.log(value);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="hello[101][]" />
```

Now this works fine.

But I am wondering if there is a better way then `...name.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];` to get the `input name array key value(s)`? Like is there a way to convert the `hello[101][]` string to a kind of javascript array or object? Like what if I want to get all keys from:

```
<input type="text" name="hello['one'][101]['test'][]" />
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't follow this pattern myself - but you could use `eval()` to process that string as code

Comment: @hackerrdave thanks for your comment, am I doing something wrong with `eval()`? doesn't shows anything https://jsfiddle.net/yv4ceffr/ `input.name` is a string though

Comment: I suggest using ids instead of names to reference the elements on the client side, and format the ids in such a way that they are easy to work with.  Names are really for the server (IMHO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an eval example

```js
var str = "hello['one'][101]['test'][]", 
  parts=eval(str.substring(str.indexOf("[")).split("][").join(","))
console.log(parts)
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan! Much appreciated, will accept in the near future if no better answer occurs!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a regular expression to `split()` method to make an array for you. It can be done pretty much the same way.

```
var arrayOfIntputValues = input.name.split(/\[(.*?)\]/)
```

But it will return `["hello", "'one'", "", "101", "", "'test'", "", "", ""]` so you have to delete empty elements.

```
arrayOfInputVaules.filter(function(x){return x!=''})
```